# JS don't passes data in POST request to the php file, or php can't recieve it

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have a JS function that has to pass two variables to the php file by POST, however variables in php are "Null"

JS script

```js
function a(){
var name = document.getElementById("fio");
var tel = document.getElementById("tel");
    if(name!=""&&tel!="")
    {
         dannie = {'polz_name':name, 'polz_tel':tel};
         $.post('senda.php', dannie, function(otvet_serv){
               rezultat = '<div style="color:#D80018;">'+otvet_serv.text+'</div>';
               $("#form_result").hide().html(rezultat).slideDown();
         }, 'json');
    }
}
```

PHP file

```php
$user_Name = filter_var($_POST["polz_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_Phone = filter_var($_POST["polz_tel"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Are you do the console.log(name)....???

Comment: Thank you, yes, they are Null already in js part
Now I just have to figure out why

Comment: remove json in your $.post

Comment: @Qonvex620 why?
I just fixed my issue, and it works well with json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html part of the document "fio" and "tel" was names, not ids. I added id parameter to them, and it worked